# Oracle SQL row concatenation by periods

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| LAUFD | ID | NEXDT | ORDER_ROW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20140305 | C1 | 20140310 | 14 |
| 20140226 | C1 | 20140305 | 13 |
| 20131125 | C1 | 20131126 | 12 |
| 20131021 | C1 | 20131022 | 11 |
| 20130821 | C1 | 20130828 | 10 |
| 20130814 | C1 | 20130821 | 9 |
| 20130807 | C1 | 20130814 | 8 |
| 20130731 | C1 | 20130807 | 7 |
| 20130724 | C1 | 20130731 | 6 |
| 20130710 | C1 | 20130724 | 5 |
| 20130708 | C1 | 20130709 | 4 |
| 20130624 | C1 | 20130707 | 3 |
| 20130603 | C1 | 20130608 | 2 |
| 20130527 | C1 | 20130603 | 1 |

I would like to have the below output:

| ID | START | END | PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 20140226 | 20140310 | 5 |
| C1 | 20131125 | 20131126 | 4 |
| C1 | 20131021 | 20131022 | 3 |
| C1 | 20130624 | 20130828 | 2 |
| C1 | 20130527 | 20130608 | 1 |

The logic is: if, ordering ID by order_row, the field NEXDT is equal or equal+1 or equal+2 to the field LAUFD of the next order_row, then continue with the next entry. If not, generate an entry in the output table with the start (earliest LAUFD) and end (latest NEXDT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use `lag()` and then a cumulative sum:

```
select id, min(laufd), max(nextdt),
       row_number() over (partition by id order by min(laufd)) as period
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_nextdt >= laufd - interval '2' day then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by id order by order_row) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(nextdt) over (partition by id order by order_row) as prev_nextdt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, id;
```

EDIT:

If the values are stored as strings, then use:

```
select id, min(laufd), max(nextdt),
       row_number() over (partition by id order by min(laufd)) as period
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_nextdt >= laufd - interval '2' day then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by id order by order_row) as grp
      from (select t.id, t.order_row, -- any other columns you need
                   to_date(laufd, 'YYYYMMDD') as laufd,
                   to_date(nextdt, 'YYYYMMDD') as next_dt,
                   lag(to_date(nextdt, 'YYYYMMDD')) over (partition by id order by order_row) as prev_nextdt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp, id;
```

Comment: Mention the data types of the column.

Comment: Instead of interval, I needed to put just -2 because my DBAs like storing dates a varchars.

Comment: @JaviTorre . . . Convert the values to dates!  If you use numbers, the logic will not be valid at the end of months.

Comment: Any special reason for storing dates in varchar?

Answer (score 1):

For your temporary solution with varchar2 datatype
I simplified a little bit using common table expressions.
But as mentioned by @gordon this logic will fail for the last day and the first day of the next month.

```
with cte as (SELECT order_row, id, to_number(laufd) laufd, to_number(nextdt) nextdt, lag(to_number(nextdt)) OVER (ORDER BY order_row) AS prev_nextdt FROM table1 ORDER BY order_row),

cte2 as (SELECT id, laufd, nextdt, prev_nextdt, sum(case when prev_nextdt >= laufd - 2 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by order_row) as grp
  FROM cte)

select  id, min(laufd) "START", max(nextdt) "END", grp as period FROM cte2 GROUP BY grp, id order by grp desc;
```