# Oracle SQL row concatenation by periods: maximum period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| LAUFD | ID | NEXDT | ORDER_ROW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20140305 | C1 | 20140310 | 14 |
| 20140226 | C1 | 20140305 | 13 |
| 20131125 | C1 | 20131126 | 12 |
| 20131021 | C1 | 20131022 | 11 |
| 20130821 | C1 | 20130828 | 10 |
| 20130814 | C1 | 20130821 | 9 |
| 20130807 | C1 | 20130814 | 8 |
| 20130731 | C1 | 20130807 | 7 |
| 20130724 | C1 | 20130731 | 6 |
| 20130710 | C1 | 20130724 | 5 |
| 20130708 | C1 | 20130709 | 4 |
| 20130624 | C1 | 20130707 | 3 |
| 20130603 | C1 | 20130608 | 2 |
| 20130527 | C1 | 20130603 | 1 |

I would like to have the below output:

| ID | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 20140226 | 20140310 |

The logic is: if, ordering ID by order_row, the field NEXDT is equal or equal+1 or equal+2 to the field LAUFD of the next order_row, then continue with the next entry. If not, generate an entry in the output table with the start (earliest LAUFD) and end (latest NEXDT).

Basically, it's the same question as in [Oracle SQL row concatenation by periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67161619/oracle-sql-row-concatenation-by-periods) but I'd like just the latest period as an output.

Comment: what is your oracle version? I just need to check if your version support match_recognize

Comment: what are types of LAUFD and NEXDT? DATE? or number?

Comment: Types: number, version 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you need:

```sql
with t (LAUFD, ID,  NEXDT, ORDER_ROW) as (
  select 20140305,'C1', 20140310, 14  from dual union all
  select 20140226,'C1', 20140305, 13  from dual union all
  select 20131125,'C1', 20131126, 12  from dual union all
  select 20131021,'C1', 20131022, 11  from dual union all
  select 20130821,'C1', 20130828, 10  from dual union all
  select 20130814,'C1', 20130821, 9   from dual union all
  select 20130807,'C1', 20130814, 8   from dual union all
  select 20130731,'C1', 20130807, 7   from dual union all
  select 20130724,'C1', 20130731, 6   from dual union all
  select 20130710,'C1', 20130724, 5   from dual union all
  select 20130708,'C1', 20130709, 4   from dual union all
  select 20130624,'C1', 20130707, 3   from dual union all
  select 20130603,'C1', 20130608, 2   from dual union all
  select 20130527,'C1', 20130603, 1   from dual 
)
,t1 as (select id, order_row, to_date(laufd,'yyyymmdd') as laufd_dt, to_date(nexdt,'yyyymmdd') as nexdt_dt from t)
select *
from t1
match_recognize (
  partition by id
  order by order_row desc
  measures
    min(x.laufd_dt) as dt_start,
    max(a.nexdt_dt) as dt_end,
    x.laufd_dt-next(x.nexdt_dt) as dates_diff
  one row per match
  pattern(a x+ y* z*)
  define
    x as x.order_row=prev(order_row)-1 and prev(laufd_dt)-nexdt_dt<=3
   ,y as x.order_row=prev(order_row)-1 
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll evaluate the performance for bigger tables and come back to decide on the best answer :)

Comment: I can't help but notice that some of the values for dates_diff are null in a bigger table. What could this be due to?

Comment: Dates_diff is just a difference between the dates.

Comment: ID   DT_START DT_END  DATES_DIFF
ID1  05-MAR-21 19-MAR-21 17
ID2  22-JAN-21 05-FEB-21 (null)
ID3  08-FEB-21 17-FEB-21 (null)
ID4  08-FEB-21 22-MAR-21 (null)

Comment: @JaviTorre you don't need dates_diff, just ignore or remove it. So are other columns correct? If not, please provide your test data and required output.

Answer (score 1):

For just the latest period, you could use the previous solution.  But instead, look for the first "break".  Then only use the rows since that break;

```
select id, min(laufd), max(nextdt),
       row_number() over (partition by id order by min(laufd)) as period
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_nextdt >= laufd - interval '2' day then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by id order by order_row range desc) as grp,
             sum(case when prev_nextdt >= laufd - interval '2' day then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id) as num_grps
      from (select t.id, t.order_row, -- any other columns you need
                   to_date(laufd, 'YYYYMMDD') as laufd,
                   to_date(nextdt, 'YYYYMMDD') as next_dt,
                   lag(to_date(nextdt, 'YYYYMMDD')) over (partition by id order by order_row) as prev_nextdt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where num_grps = grp
group by id;
```

This is basically the same logic.  It just keeps the first group.